# How to choose 1 row among rows with characteristic like this

Tags: sql, dataframe

| sku1 | sku2 | intersection | sku1_order | sku2_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chocopie Orion 6packs 198g - 20373 | Chocopie Orion Cacao 6pack180g - 25163 | 4 | 29 | 10 |
| Chocopie Orion Cacao 6pack180g - 25163 | Chocopie Orion 6packs 198g - 20373 | 4 | 10 | 29 |

How do I write SQL to pick only 1 row if there are >= 2 rows with characteristics like this? Sku1 and Sku2 are cross each other.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you update your question with the SQL query you are doing to get this result?

Comment: `group by least(sku1_order, sku2_order), greatest(sku1_order, sku2_order)`